# Can you install new certificates on Apache 2.2 without a restart?

Tags: apache-2.2

Can this be done with gracefull or is a restart necesary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `apachectl graceful`.

Apache will reload with the new changes including the certificates, but will not abort the active connections.